# LeafletJS, streamlined way to enter datapoints

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I created [this interactive toggle map](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_toggle_map/blob/master/yorba.html) with LeafletJS

If you [see the source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_toggle_map/master/yorba.txt), there are over 70 datapoints.

However, I am working on a project with over 1500 datapoints.

Is there a streamlined way for entering over 1500 datapoints?

R was simple because it read CSV, and I had to go Javascript route to toggle the map layers and datapoints.

Please tell me there is something more efficient than concating 1500+ rows in EXCEL and creating input string to copy and paste into source code.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a vector of longitude coordinates and a vector of latitude coordinates. It will then autoplot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using R (I use Rstudio), you can add the Leaflet package (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/ it has some prerequisites). First you load the CSV as a dataframe, then you add a marker layer from it with a one liner (see https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html)

For the layer control follow this example https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html

Comment: I was able to use R to create similar map, except you cannot change between street/satellite or toggle the legend keys, http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/web_Yorba_Linda.html. I am trying to determine how to toggle these views in R program without using Javascript, i.e. `L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);`

Comment: You can create a layer control as in this example https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html

Answer (score 1):

Following shows a toggle between street and image as well as a two separate data observations done in leaflet.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
d <- read.table("http://www.hafro.is/hafroskip/sild.data",header=F)
names(d) <- c("id","date","lon","lat","cm1","cm2")
d$date <- lubridate::ymd_hm(d$date)
x1 <- d %>%
  filter(id == 101109)
x2 <- d %>%
  filter(id == 101143)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", group="streetmap") %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
           group="image") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data=x1, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, weight = 1, radius = 4, col="yellow",
                   popup = ~date, group="Less than something") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data=x2, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, weight = 1, radius = 4, col="green",
                   popup = ~date, group="More than something") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("streetmap","image"),
    overlayGroups = c("Less than something","More than something"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

hope this is analogous to what you were looking for.

einar